# Ubuntu 16.04 Software & Updates default settings

Tags: 16.04

My Windows Network Admin screwed up my Ubuntu default settings
I could just go on and enable everything, but I don't want that,
Can someone share screenshots of their Ubuntu 16.04's Software & Updates default settings? Of all the tabs inside it -

1. Ubuntu Software
2. Other Software
3. Updates
4. Authentication
5. Additional Drivers
6. Developer Options

This could be really helpful of newbies like me.

Answer (score 3):

1. On the first tab everything is enabled by default.
2. It depends on what additional PPA you are using. Initially nothing is there.
3. Everything should be enabled there.
4. Keys for the enabled repos are shown. You can press reset to defaults there.
5. This depends on your hardware.
6. This should be disabled.